# Pandas groupby agg returns multiindex columns how to remove multiindex?

Tags: pandas, group-by, aggregate, multi-index

I am trying to understand how to remove multiindex columns after applying groupby and agg - see below, last command returns  (Target, count), (Target, sum) multiindex columns but I want a data frame without multiindex

```
# Sample Data Creation
lst_Purchase_Date = ['2022-02-28','2022-02-28','2022-02-28','2022-03-01','2022-03-01']
lst_Target = [0,0,1,1,1]
df_test = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst_Purchase_Date,lst_Target)),columns=['Purchase_Date','Target'])
df_test.head()

    Purchase_Date   Target
0   2022-02-28        0
1   2022-02-28        0
2   2022-02-28        1
3   2022-03-01        1
4   2022-03-01        1
```

Using groupby and agg results in column multi-index

```
result = df_test.groupby('Purchase_Date').agg(['sum','count'])
result = result.reset_index()
result.head()

    Purchase_Date   Target
                   sum  count
0   2022-02-28       1  3
1   2022-03-01       2  2
```

I need result like below

```
Purchase_Date Target_Sum Target_Count
2022-02-28       1            3
2022-03-01       2            2
```

Comment: `df.groupby('Purchase_Date')['Target'].agg(['sum','count']).add_prefix('Target_')`

Comment: Thanks, however I still see multi-index see below result.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column                         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                         --------------  ----- 
 0   (Purchase_Date, )              2 non-null      object
 1   (Target_Target, Target_sum)    2 non-null      int64 
 2   (Target_Target, Target_count)  2 non-null      int64 
dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a more verbose syntax for agg where you get to specify the column names on the left, then the column to operate on, then the function to apply

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Purchase_Date': 
     {0: '2022-02-28',
      1: '2022-02-28',
      2: '2022-02-28',
      3: '2022-03-01',
      4: '2022-03-01'},
 'Target': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}}
)

result = df.groupby('Purchase_Date').agg(
    Target_Sum = ('Target','sum'),
    Target_Count = ('Target','count'),
)

result
```

Comment: thanks, this worked - I just had to `result.reset_index()` to get this in the format I wanted